# How to use nested each loop in Azure DevOps YAML

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-devops, yaml

Below is piece of code I am trying to put in each loop in YAML pipeline.
Can anyone help ?

```
  parameters:
  - name: parameter1
    type: object
    default:
      IN:
        Test1:
          folderPath: abc/myFolder1
        Test2:
          folderPath: abc/myFolder2     
        Test3:
          folderPath: abc/myFolder3
      US:
        Test4:
          folderPath: xyz/myFolder4
      CA:
        Test5:
          folderPath: lmn/myFolder5
```

Comment: did you get any solution ?